# Can we use Pindrop instead of Pindrop silence in a sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

The director of our English training institute told us that we must use pindrop instead of pindrop silence. I have searched on the internet to find out the correct way of using this word but I could only find the usage of pindrop silence.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How are you trying to use these words? An example would show what you thought was or wasn't correct.

Comment: Note that in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pin-drop) **pin-drop** isn't a noun but an adjective. Perhaps that is why your search for a 'pindrop' noun was fruitless.

Comment: to **hear a pin drop** =idiomatic expression. It is an expression.

Comment: An example sentence is needed, the director may have criticised "you could hear a pindrop silence" with the suggestion "you could hear a pin drop."

Comment: I can't imagine any circumstance where I would use "pindrop" as a noun though I can imagine a literary or poetic use of "pindrop silence". Without full context it's difficult to know what the director is talking about. In the idiomatic sentence "You could hear a pin drop." "Pin drop" is a normal subject and verb relationship. What you can hear (metaphrically) is the sound of a pin falling to the floor. If the director had said "Don't use 'pindrop', it's not a word " I would have  agreed with him but I can accept it more easily as an adjective than as a noun.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with "pindrop" as a single word, but [there is a dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pindrop-silence) for the phrase "pindrop silence," including having "pindrop" as a single word. It is tagged as "Indian English." What I'm more used to, in UK and US English, is the more wordy idiom "[it was so quiet] you could have heard a pin drop." (Note, "pin drop" in this case is two words.)

Perhaps your teacher was directing you away from a usage that wouldn't be local to your context (unless you're specifically learning Indian usages). But I'm not aware of a usage that would use "pindrop," on its own, as an adjective or adverb (though, as noted in the comments, the hyphenated adjectival "pin-drop" could be readily understood).